# I'm looking for a word that describes that moment you feel overwhelmed by the beauty and grandeur of nature

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, verbs

I was on a mountain the other day and had a moment where I just had to stop and take it all in. I felt insignificant (in the best way) and just stopped to admire where I was. The closest words I could find was something along the lines of biophilia, or the German word Waldeinsamkeit.

Comment: I didn't know what *waldeinsamkeit* meant, so I googled it and turned up [this poem](http://www.infoplease.com/t/poetry/emerson-poems/waldeinsamkeit.html) by Ralph Waldo Emerson that you might appreciate.

Comment: "[stunning] extravaganza of nature" ?

Comment: Sounds like you had a case of the double rainbows.

Comment: *waldeinsamkeit* is a feeling of loneliness and plenitude when connected to forest or nature.

Answer (score 7):

While not nature specific, *awestruck* seems to be suitable.

Comment: You could improve this answer by citing a dictionary's definition, and perhaps including a sentence using this word. I think it's a very apt choice. It fits in very nicely with the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

- [Entranced](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entranced): If you are entranced by someone or something that is very ​interesting or ​beautiful, you cannot ​stop ​watching him, her, or it:

> *The ​children ​sat ​silent on the ​carpet, entranced by the ​puppet show.*
>   [Cambridge Dictionaries Online]

Synonyms: captivated, enraptured, enthralled.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same experience and I always forget the word, but I think “Sublime” describes nature of this kind perfectly. Here is the definition: “of such excellence, grandeur, or beauty as to inspire great admiration or awe”.

Comment: Sublime is what the thing ***is*** that makes you feel awe not “the moment you feel overwhelmed by ... nature”