# overwhelmed by mountains

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I was once told of a word describing how utterly overwhelmed you feel when looking at mountains.
Not sure if the word describes the actual mountains, or how you feel

Comment: Awe inspiring? Insignificant?

Comment: Maybe one of the answers to this question: [I'm looking for a word that describes that moment you feel overwhelmed by the beauty and grandeur of nature](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308004/im-looking-for-a-word-that-describes-that-moment-you-feel-overwhelmed-by-the-be/308011#308011)

Comment: @charlotte "awestruck" maybe. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/awestruck

Comment: "Humbled" might work in some contexts.  But, oddly, really *seeing* mountains also produces a sense of peace that somehow needs to be fit into the equation.

Comment: I think Homer Simpson would call the feeling you're talking about _ensmallened_.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of this called "**seeing the elephant**": [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seeing_the_elephant)

> refers to gaining experience of the world at a significant cost.